# Directory listing from FileZilla Server fail with 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "..."

Tags: networking, ftp, filezilla

If I am on my LAN I can connect problem free using the IP of my server.  If I am outside (and this just started happening today) of my LAN and I try to connect to my server, this is the error I get:

> Status: Resolving address of XXXX.XXXX.org
>   Status: Connecting to XX.XX.XXX.168
>   Status: Connected, performing TLS handshake...
>   Status: TLS handshake successful, verifying certificate...
>   Status: Waiting for welcome message...
>   Reply: 220-FileZilla Server 0.9.53 beta
>   Reply: 220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
>   Reply: 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
>   Command: CLNT https://ftptest.net on behalf of XX.XX.X.131
>   Reply: 200 Don't care
>   Command: USER XXXXX
>   Reply: 331 Password required for XXXXX
>   Command: PASS ******
>   Reply: 230 Logged on
>   Command: SYST
>   Reply: 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
>   Command: FEAT
>   Reply: 211-Features:
>   Reply: MDTM
>   Reply: REST STREAM
>   Reply: SIZE
>   Reply: MLST type*;size*;modify*;
>   Reply: MLSD
>   Reply: AUTH SSL
>   Reply: AUTH TLS
>   Reply: PROT
>   Reply: PBSZ
>   Reply: UTF8
>   Reply: CLNT
>   Reply: MFMT
>   Reply: EPSV
>   Reply: EPRT
>   Reply: 211 End
>   Command: PBSZ 0
>   Reply: 200 PBSZ=0
>   Command: PROT P
>   Reply: 200 Protection level set to P
>   Command: PWD
>   Reply: 257 "/" is current directory.
>   Status: Current path is /
>   Command: TYPE I
>   Reply: 200 Type set to I
>   Command: PASV
>   Reply: 227 Entering Passive Mode (XX,XX,XX,XXX,166,216)
>   Command: MLSD
>   Reply: 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
>   Error: Listing failed

What do I do to resolve this?  I am running FileZilla Server that I am trying to connect to.  The user I am logging in as has valid credentials and am connecting on the appropriate port.  I am using FileZilla Client version 3.8.0 to try and connect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Command: PASV
>   Reply: 227 Entering Passive Mode (XX,XX,XX,XXX,166,216)
>   Command: MLSD
>   Reply: 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"

The data connection port on your FTP server is not accessible.

The port number for this specific connection was 42712 (=166*256+216). But in general, there's a port range. So that whole port range needs to be made accessible.

[image]

Check all firewalls (both internal on the FTP server machine and external) and NATs on the way between your client and the server. They all need to allow and correctly route the connections to the ports in the data connection port range.

For details, see

- [Setting up and testing FileZilla Server](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Setting_up_and_testing_FileZilla_Server)
- Or *my* generic article [network configuration required by FTP protocol](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).